# HashSet of ByteBuffer(actually integers) to separate unique & non unique elements from a ByteBuffer array

Tags: java, arrays, hashset, bytebuffer

I have an array of `ByteBuffer`s(which actually represent integers). I want to the separate unique & non unique ByteBuffers (i.e integers) in the array. Thus I am using HashSet of this type:
`HashSet<ByteBuffer> columnsSet = new HashSet<ByteBuffer>()`

Just wanted to know if `HashSet` is a good way to do so? And do I pay more costs, when doing so for a `ByteBuffer` then if I would have done it for a `Integer`?

(Actually I am reading serialized data from DB which needs to be written back after this operation thus I want to avoid serialization and deserialization between bytebuffer to Integer and back!)

Your thoughts upon this appreciated.

Comment: So *each* `ByteBuffer` represents **one** `Integer`?

Comment: yes each `bytebuffer` is one `integer`! an integer value stored in DB is deserialized back as bytebuffer and then operated on.. and then the bytebuffer is saved back to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it will work. The overhead of `equals()` on two `ByteBuffer`s will definitely be higher, but perhaps not enough to offset the benefits of not having to deserialize (though, I'm not entirely sure if that would be such a big problem).

I'm pretty sure that the performance will asymptotically be the same, but a more memory-efficient solution is to sort your array, then step through it linearly and test successive elements for equality.

An example, suppose your buffers contain the following:

```
1 2 5 1
```

Sort it:

```
1 1 2 5
```

Once you start iterating, you get `ar[0].equals(ar[1])` and you know these are duplicates. Just keep going like that till `n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a ByteBuffer is far more expensive than reading/writing from a reused ByteBuffer.

The most efficient way to store integers is to use `int` type. If you want a Set of these you can use TIntHashSet which uses int primitives.  You can do multiple read/deserialize/store and reverse with O(1) pre-allocated objects.

Answer (score 0):

Collections normally operate on the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, so performance implications would come through the implementation of the objects stored in the collection.

Looking at `ByteBuffer` and `Integer` one can see that the implementation of those methods in `Integer` are simpler (just one int comparison for `equals()` and `return value;` for `hashCode()`). Thus you could say the `Set<ByteBuffer>` has higher cost than a `Set<Integer>`.

However, I can't tell you right now if this cost is higher than the serialization and deserialization cost.

In fact, I'd just go for the more readable code unless you really have a performance problem. In that case I'd just try both methods and take the faster one.